# Passing variables in a multi-project solution

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working with a progaram called aspdotnetstorefront.
This is a shopping cart program
The solution has 7 projects in it

There is a file in the web project that is called checkout1.cs that has the checkout1.aspx file

The checkout1.aspx file has a field for state. In the solution, there is project called aspdnsfcommons which has a file called Shoppingcart.cs.

I have tried everything to take the value of the state textbox from web/check1.aspx and pass it to aspdnsfcommons/shoppingcart.cs

Please advice me of the direction I should take.

Answer (score 3):

Add a reference to aspdnsfcommons in your project. There should be a state property in Shoppingcart.cs with write access (set property) that you can use to achieve this.

Comment: Solution Resoved: I have already done that. What I wanted to do is pass the variable from the checkout1.cs to the shoppingcart.cs page. What I did was create a key in the webconfig file called mystate under appsettings. (<add key="mystate" value="" />)Then I pulled the appsettings key: System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mystate"] = bresult3 - (bresult3 was the variable) onto the checkout1.cs Then I went to the shoppingcart.cs page and added it where I needed it. Thanks again IrishChiefain for your reply. This was don for aspdotnetstorefront ver 8.00